# PHP MYSQL Showing multiple values from LEFT JOIN from a query

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have two tables showing a list of customers and their corresponding ratings. Most of the customers have more than one rating each. I would like to show a list of all the customers and their ratings. I am extracted this info from the database and using php to show it in a file. This is what I am getting for example:

```
customer1 - rating
customer1 - rating
customer1 - rating
customer2 - rating
customer2 - rating
customer3 - rating
```

This is what I want:

```
customer1 - rating
          - rating
          - rating
customer2 - rating
          - rating
customer3 - rating
```

There are certain things I need to do to the rating. Some will be approved and some not and only the approved ones will be used. Those approved ones should be added together and an average found.

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("
        SELECT *, AVG(rating) AS rating_avg 
        FROM companies 
            LEFT JOIN ratings ON companies.id = ratings.company_id
        WHERE category LIKE ?
        AND location LIKE ? 
        GROUP BY companies.id   
        ORDER BY FIELD(type, 'premium', 'standard', 'basic')");
```

This is my coding so far which is not working as the SQL statement doesn't differentiate between the approved and not approved. Also, all companies must show whether they have a rating or not, but not all ratings should show.

`

```
$sqlb ="SELECT *
                    FROM companies";
    $resultb = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlb);
    $row = array();


   while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultb))) {
          $id = $row['id'];
      echo $company_name = $row['company_name'];//what is the column name


        $stmt = $conn->prepare("
            SELECT * 
            FROM ratings 
            WHERE ratings.company_id = ?
            "); 


        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);        
        $stmt->execute();   
        $result = $stmt->get_result();



        while(($ratings = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) {

                 if ($ratings['approve'] == 'approved') {
                     echo '<br />';
                     echo $ratings['rating'].' ';
                     echo $ratings['review'];
                 } //if

                } //while ratings
 echo '<hr />';

     } //while
```

`

Comment: There's three kinds of quotes used in MySQL. Single (`'`) and double (`"`) are by default the same, they enclose string values. Backticks are used on [identifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html).

Comment: I found an answer to my question and managed to solve this issue after day 3!

Comment: Please don't update your question with a solution. The answer section is for solutions. If the answer is different to any of the ones on the suggested duplicate then please post there.

Comment: In the stackoverflow comment box I am writing right now it says: 'Use comments to reply to other users or notify them of changes. If you are adding new information, edit your post instead of commenting'. So which is it Bugs?

Comment: Since it's already been flagged as a duplicate we can de-flag it and allow Wendy to post that as an answer. It could be helpful for other people in the same jam. Is that last block of code an answer? The phrasing isn't quite clear as it implies there's still some problems with it.